# DataTable Error - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am trying to build my DataTable (1.10.5) using an ajax call to a service  - http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/

Here is my Javascript:

```
$('#tableexample').DataTable({

    "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "../../api/EventTypes/GetAll",
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      {
          "aTargets": [0],
          "mData": "Id"
      },
       {
           "aTargets": [1], 
           "mData": "Name"
       },
       {
           "aTargets": [2],
           "mData": "Name"
       },
       {
           "aTargets": [3],
           "mData": "Name"
       },
       {
           "aTargets": [4],
           "mData": "Name"
       }
    ]
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="tableexample" class="table table-striped dataTable table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Select</th>
                                <th>Event</th>
                                <th>Primary Category</th>
                                <th>Secondary Category</th>
                                <th>Workflow</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

Here is my error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

If I look i my jquery.dataTables.js - it says that my data is undefined...

```
var data = _fnAjaxDataSrc( settings, json );
```

Can anyone help me out with setting up my ajax call properly to dynamically build my table??

Thanks!

Comment: What server side language are you using?  `"sAjaxSource": "../../api/EventTypes/GetAll"` does not look like a `php` or `asp` file.  Maybe it just isn't returning anything, because it isn't able to contact the server script.

Comment: It is an API call to get a response back from the database. My response looks like this: 

[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Abandonment Proceeding Notes"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Adversary Closed"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Adversary Proceeding Dismissed"
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "Adversary Proceeding Filed"
  }]

Comment: You don't have a `<tbody></tbody>`.  That may be what is "undefined".

Comment: Based on http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I should not need a it. But I went ahead and tried...still no luck :( Same error

Answer (score 4):

Finally found it!

I needed to make an ajax call and pass the data to "aaData":

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Portal/api/EventTypes/GetEventWorkflowDefinitions',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        assignToEventsColumns(data);
    }
});

function assignToEventsColumns(data) {
var table = $('#tableexample').dataTable({
    "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aaData": data,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
       {
           "aTargets": [0],
           "bSearchable": false,
           "bSortable": false,
           "bSort": false,
           "mData": "EventTypeId",
           "mRender": function (event) {
               return '<input class="childCheck" type="checkbox" id="childCheckBoxes" value="' + event + '">';
           }
       },
       {
           "aTargets": [1], 
           "mData": "EventType"
       }
```

Once I did this...the table build perfectly!